# JavaCompiler API - slow compilation when running in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, javac, java-compiler-api, javacompiler

My application generates java code during runtime and compiles it using the JavaCompiler API. Some of the generated files can be rather large - up to a few hundred thousand lines. I find that when I run the `javac` command on the generated code in the command line, or alternatively if I use an application that does just the compilation via the JavaCompiler API, I can compile many of these files (~500), even if they are very large, in under two minutes. However, if I call the API via my application when it is running on a Tomcat server, the compilation time runs upwards of twelve minutes (!!!).

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve the performance of the compilation.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot place my finger on exactly why, but when I switched from using the default system compiler via a call to `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` but instead used Eclipse's JDT compiler, things sped up significantly. An explanation will happily be accepted as the answer.

Comment: a guess would be eclipse has an incremental compiler so it isn't doing a clean build every time. This could be wrong though. Also doesn't answer the main question

Comment: from looking at the jvm with jvisualvm it looks like javac runs the entire compilation in a single thread, while EclipseCompiler starts many many threads to compile the `.java` files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the thread priority to the highest value (on the thread or thread pool):

```
setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```